# How to display the seconds of a digital clock widget?

Tags: android, user-interface, widget

Can anyone demonstrate how to display only the seconds part of the digital clock widget.

Comment: only seconds? Any specific purpose? Want to display CountDown purpose or else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way. Example of showing a 30 second countdown in a text field:

```
new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```